# How to add Postman test asset error or success message

Tags: testing, postman-testcase, postman-newman

In the postman I have following test. How to give assertion success or error message. I don't want to give message as console.log("my msg"). Coz console message goes to the console.I want to show the message as in the picture where postman shows pass or fail.

```
pm.test("Full version number present in response headers optional", () => {
let apiVersion = pm.response.headers.get("API-Version")
pm.expect(apiVersion).match(/[-.0-9]+/)
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official documentation in [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/).

Only can add extra message when it is failed.

Example for demo - 3rd item

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
const apiVersion = undefined
pm.test('Full version number present in response', function () {
    pm.expect(apiVersion).match(/[-.0-9]+/)
});

const apiVersion1 = '1.2.3'
pm.test('Full version number present in response', function () {
    pm.expect(apiVersion1).match(/[-.0-9]+/)
});

pm.test('Full version number present in response', function () {
    pm.expect(null,"extrame message").match(/[-.0-9]+/)
});
```

[image]